# SE for walkthrough-like community

Tags: feature-request

I find myself in the situation where I need to start working with a set of new technologies, for example: (Ubuntu, Python, Django, PostgreSQL, Virtualenv...) and I had to figure out how to start using the technologies by trying and testing different versions and installing uninstalling. It would be awesome to have a SE for specific steps to follow on different stacks/environments and that could be tried by different users and upvote or comment or changes on some detail. That way a strong collection of development stacks/environments could be found in one place, and not in different sites and languages and architecture dependent to some point.

Comment: If you have a new site to propose, take it to http://area51.stackexchange.com Though from reading your question, I'm not clear on whether it would fit in the network.

Answer (score 3):

New site proposals go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/

But really, such a site won't really fit the SE model -- what you want is a *wiki*. SE-sites are meant to be focused on a particular topic. This spans all topics, and instead constrains the *type* of posts. In the end, there would probably be one looong CW answer per question. Which doesn't really fit the SE model.

Besides, you can ask for a walkthrough on other SE sites (Game walkthroughs on [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), software on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), etc). You can also self-answer a post if you have created a walkthrough and wish to post it. While "Getting started" questions are generally off topic everywhere(see? another reason why the SE model/policies won't fit your site., "how do I do X?" isn't.

Comment: The self-answering mechanism is sort of built to support this. It's not always a perfect fit, but in principle one could post a question and answer it in a tutorial format if it made sense to do so for that question.

Comment: @AnnaLear: It is, but having _every single post on the site_ as a long self-answer means that you're doing it wrong :/

Comment: My point is more that this is already possible on existing sites. No need for a new one.

Comment: @AnnaLear: ah, I see, added. Thanks :)